# How many threads should Jenkins run?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins server that keeps running out of memory and cannot create native threads. I've upped the memory and installed the [Monitoring plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring).

There are about 150 projects on the server, and I've been watching the thread count creep up all day. It is now around 990. I expect when it hits 1024, which is the user limit for threads, Jenkins will run out of memory again.

`[edit]: I have hit 1016 threads and am now getting the out of memory error`

Is this an appropriate number of threads for Jenkins to be running? How can I tell Jenkins to destroy threads when it is finished with them?

Comment: @ruffin, LOL, but please keep your comments professional

Comment: Can you post the error message from the Jenkins log when it runs out of threads ?

Comment: Also, please indicate which version of Jenkins you are using.

Comment: I'm not at my workstation, but I can confirm I am running the most recent version ( > 1.4.3). The error went something along the lines of `Out of Memory: unable to create native thread`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

There was a post-build action running a bash script that didn't return anything via stderr or stdout to Jenkins. Therefore, every time the build ran, threads would be created and get stuck `wait`ing. I resolved this issue by having the bash script return an `exit` status.

**long answer**

I am running Jenkins on CentOS and have installed in via the RPM. In terms of modifying the Winstone servlet container, you can change that in Jenkin's init script in `/etc/sysctrl/jenkins`. However the options above only control the number of HTTP threads that are created, not the number of threads overall.

That would be a solution if my threads were hanging on accessing an HTTP API of Jenkins as part of a post-commit action. However, using the ever-handy Monitoring plugin mentioned in my question, I inspected the stuck threads.

The threads were stuck on something in the `com.trilead.ssh2.channel` package. The `getChannelData` method has a `while(true)` loop that looks for output on the `stderr` or `stdout` of an ssh stream. The thread was getting suck in that loop because nothing was coming through. I learned this on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson/trilead-ssh2/build212-hudson-6/com/trilead/ssh2/channel/ChannelManager.java#ChannelManager.getChannelData%28com.trilead.ssh2.channel.Channel,boolean,byte%5B%5D,int,int%29).

This was because the post-build action was to execute a command via SSH onto a server and execute a bash script that would inspect a git repo. However, the git repo was misconfigured and the git command would error, but the `exit 1` status did not bubble up through the bash script (partially due to a misformed if-elif-else statement).

The script completed and the build was considered a success, but somehow the thread handling the SSH connection from Jenkins was left hanging due to this git error.

But thank you for your help on this question!

Answer (score 2):

If you run Jenkins "out of the box" it uses Winstone servlet container. You can pass command-line arguments to it as [described here](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#commandLine). Some of those parameters can limit the number of threads:

```
 --handlerCountStartup    = set the no of worker threads to spawn at startup. Default is 5
 --handlerCountMax        = set the max no of worker threads to allow. Default is 300
 --handlerCountMaxIdle    = set the max no of idle worker threads to allow. Default is 50
```

Now, I tried this some time ago and was not 100% convinced that it worked, so no guarantees, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: to verify that this is not working, you can add the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring Jenkins plugin, and it shows the number of threads configured in the 6th block. And using the options above has no effect.